# Gradient derivation reference for Phased LSTM

Tags: gradient-descent, lstm

I've worked-through the back-propagation for the [Phased LSTM (Daniel Neil, Michael Pfeiffer, and Shih-Chii Liu 2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09513.pdf) and would like to show the notes. It was a relatively difficult task, so I post it here, to help if anyone struggles with derivation.

I assume you know how to do the back-prop for the usual LSTM, and so will show only the most critical gradient-pieces.

Keep in mind the gradient flows in to opposite direction of the arrow.
The Phased LSTM uses Peepholes.

Also, notice, the authors skip some timesteps by referring to the "most recent update time" as $t_j$  but I am using just $t$ for everything. That's because during training we need to consider every timestep - there is a "leak" in the time gate. However, as the paper advises, the leak is turned off at runtime, and you can then use $t_j$ and skip any 'non-j' timesteps to save performance.

**Note - there still might be an error in the notes, although I've checked it thoroughly, and also via Gradient Check procedure. Still, please let me know if you spot one.**

[Here is a link regarding partial derivatives through the modulo operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651437/partial-of-modulo-operator-with-non-integers)

**Tools to be used:**

The quotient rule says:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{a_i}} \left( \frac{g(a_i)}{h(a_i)} \right) = \frac{\frac{\partial{g(a_i)}}{\partial{a_i}}h(a_i) - g(a_i)\frac{\partial{h(a_i)}}{\partial{a_i}}}{h(a_i)^2}$$

and the the Chain rule says:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{a_i}} [ g(h(a_i))] = \frac{\partial{g(h(a_i))}}{\partial{h(a_i)}}\frac{\partial{h(a_i)}}{\partial{a_i}}$$

as a bonus,product rule says:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{a_i}}g(a_i)h(a_i) = \frac{\partial{g(a_i)}}{\partial{a_i}} + \frac{\partial{h(a_i)}}{\partial{a_i}}$$ 
[image]

Part #2:

[image]

Comment: Erm, this is nice, but not a good use of the site. DataScience Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, so you need to have an actual question, in order to post a question (which is what you have just done). Could I suggest you post on a blogging site - perhaps https://medium.com/ would be ok for something like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: Ok, but don't regret when you need the reference and it's nowhere)) 
MathJax tutorial is similar to my post:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: That link is on a meta site, and very relevant to users of the Math stack exchange site - it is literally about how to use a site feature. Due to those two important differences, is not similar to your post here. If you really want to create a reference for your work, then please do so on a suitable site, I am sure many people will be grateful.

Comment: Though this' a bit unususal, The stuff OP presents here is good.

Comment: I agree that you create a useful reference for a challenging problem. To align it with the Q&A style of this website, you could do the following. Create a new question that actually asks a question: 'How should I do the backpropagation for Phased LSTM'? While creating this, click 'Answer your own question'; a new field appears where you can post your answer.